# Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in line 96

Tags: php

```
function SGElemByTagName($domNode, $tagName)
        {
            return (($this->SGP_VERSION == 5) ? $domNode->getElementsByTagName($tagName) : $domNode->get_elements_by_tagname($tagName));
        }
```

this is what i have on line number 96.

Comment: check `isset($domNode)`

Answer (score 1):

That means your variable `$domNode` does not point to an object, and so it cannot respond to method calls. In other words, `$domNode` is not of the type you assume it to be.

You could branch on `isset($domNode)`, as Harikrishnan suggests. Or, a little better, you could use `is_object($domNode)` to verify it's an object before trying to call methods on it. A better design would be to not call this method at all if you don't have a valid `\DOMDocument` to pass into it. If you go that route, you can use type hinting in your method signature to force your code to throw a more useful error when invalid parameters do get used, like this:

```
function SGElemByTagName(\DOMDocument $domNode, $tagName) {
    # Your logic here
    $omg = $domNode->getElementsByTagName($tagName);
    # etc...
}
```

Then, if you were to:

```
SGElemByTagName('<div><h1>Oops!</h1></div>', 'h1');
```

you'd get an exception with the meaningful message:

> Argument 1 passed to SGElemByTagName() must be an instance of
>   DOMDocument, string given ...

Another bonus with this approach is that you and other developers that may work with this code later on will see just from the method signature what the interface is.